# Compare two dataframes, one column, and add certain values on match?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two `dataframes`

```
eqdf
  symbol   qty
0  DABIND   1 
1  INFTEC   6 
2  DISHTV   8 
3  HINDAL   40
4  NATMIN   5 
5  POWGRI   40
6  CHEPET   6 

premdf
   share  strike   lprice  premperc  d_strike
 0  HINDAL   250.0   237.90  1.975620  5.086171
 1  RELIND  1280.0  1254.30  1.642350  2.048952
 2  POWGRI   205.0   201.15  1.118568  1.913995
```

I want to compare `columns` `premdf['share']` and `eqdf['symbol']` and if there is a match `premperc`,`d_strike`,`strike` value is to be added to the end of the eqdf row in which there is a match.

I have tried

```
eqdf.loc[eqdf['symbol']==premdf['share'],eqdf['premperc'] == premdf['premperc']]
```

I keep getting errors

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Expected Output:

```
eqdf
  symbol   qty   premperc   d_strike   strike   
0  DABIND   1      NaN       NaN       NaN
1  INFTEC   6      NaN       NaN       NaN      
2  DISHTV   8      NaN       NaN       NaN 
3  HINDAL   40    1.975620  5.086171   250.0
4  NATMIN   5      NaN       NaN       NaN  
5  POWGRI   40    1.118568  1.913995   205.0
6  CHEPET   6      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `rename` and `merge`

```
eqdf.merge(premdf.rename(columns={'share': 'symbol'}), 'left')

   symbol  qty  strike  lprice  premperc  d_strike
0  DABIND    1     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN
1  INFTEC    6     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN
2  DISHTV    8     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN
3  HINDAL   40   250.0  237.90  1.975620  5.086171
4  NATMIN    5     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN
5  POWGRI   40   205.0  201.15  1.118568  1.913995
6  CHEPET    6     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I actually want the `eqdf` to get the new column `premperc` ,`d_strike`,`strike`. Updating the question.